How to send VersionedTransaction on solana using solana/wallet-adapter-react package?
Solana Community. I'm facing this while trying to sign and send Versioned transaction using @solana/wallet-adapter-react. Could really use some help in finding solution to problem. Thanks!
Docs says that versioned transactions needs to be signed before calling sendTransaction.
https://solana.com/docs/advanced/versions#:~:text=cluster%3Ddevnet%60)%3B-,INFO,.,-More%20Resources%20%23
However, @solana/wallet-adapter-react doesn't export any specific function for signTransaction.
 async sendTransaction(transaction: AarcTransaction): Promise<string> {
        console.log("Sending transaction", transaction)
        const txBuffer = this.base64ToUint8Array(transaction.data)
        console.log("Sending txBuffer", txBuffer)
        const versionedMessage = VersionedMessage.deserialize(txBuffer)
        console.log("Sending versionedMessage", versionedMessage)
        const tx = new VersionedTransaction(versionedMessage)
        console.log("Sending tx", tx, this.signMsg)

        try {
            const signature = await this.wallet.adapter.sendTransaction(
                tx,
                this.connection
            )
            return signature
        } catch (e) {
            console.error("Sending transaction Error", e)
        }

}

Error:
GOT ERROR Error: Unexpected error
    at #o (solana.js:3:232171)
    at async r.signAndSendTransaction (solana.js:3:234304)
    at async #d [as signAndSendTransaction] (solana.js:3:239241)
    at async StandardWalletAdapter.sendTransaction (adapter.ts:306:38)
    at async wr.sendMsg (WalletProviderBase.tsx:202:20)
    at async wr.sendTransaction (index.js:28:53)
    at async DepositWidgetSDK.value [as handleExecute] (index.ts:909:27)
    at async index.js:882:17
    at async onClick (index.js:1962:19)

Complete Error Stack:
https://imgur.com/AO7ihxr


Also, tried using signTransaction from AnchorWallet instance.
signMsg = useAnchorWallet()?.signTransaction

async sendTransaction(transaction: AarcTransaction): Promise<string> {
        console.log("Sending transaction", transaction)
        const txBuffer = this.base64ToUint8Array(transaction.data)
        console.log("Sending txBuffer", txBuffer)
        const versionedMessage = VersionedMessage.deserialize(txBuffer)
        console.log("Sending versionedMessage", versionedMessage)
        const tx = new VersionedTransaction(versionedMessage)
        console.log("Sending tx", tx, this.signMsg)

        if (this.signMsg) return await this.signMsg(tx)
        else {
            throw Error("Signer not found")
        }
}

Error Stack:
https://imgur.com/a/cr63nm5
